# Why QT tcpsocket.write didnt work?

Tags: python, sockets, qt4

Here is the code for Clinet:

```
QString text = ui->lineEdit->text();
if(text.isEmpty())
    return;
tcpsocket->waitForBytesWritten(300);
tcpsocket->write(text.toStdString().c_str(),text.length());
qDebug("State:%d\n",tcpsocket->state());
qDebug("%d\n",tcpsocket->flush());
ui->lineEdit->clear();
```

The state is 3 and flush return 1
But why my server cant get the message?
My server is written by py,and I can telnet it successfully!

Comment: Why do you wait for bytes written before writing?

Comment: Perhaps your server waits for new line character?

Comment: Code Painiters is right! Thank you!